# Trim validation javascript not returning values

Tags: javascript

my code does not want to return the values it used to validate. Basically the code checks if there was an input in the fields and if there is not input it shows a message if there is then it should be ok. The issue is that my code does not return the values.

```
var validation = true;
var values = {};
if ($.trim($("#name").val()) == "") {
    $("#validateName").show();
    validation = false;
} else {
    $("#validateName").hide();
    values[field.name] = field.value;
}   
values['addmessage'] = '';
$.ajax({
    'url' : '',
    'type' : 'POST',
    'data' : values,
    success : function(data){

    }
```

Basically I am having issues returning my values afterwords. The values[field.name] code is written wrong. How can I fix my code?

Comment: your code is incomplete.

Comment: No I think on the else is wayyyy wrong

Comment: Validation is better to start with default state being `false` and you set the conditions in which validation is `true`. Otherwise you're letting everything pass unless you've thought of the scenario in which to fail it. Safer to have it the other way around imo

Comment: Where is the variable `field` being defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, correct your code sintaxe:

```
var validation = true;
var values = {};
if ($.trim($("#name").val()) == "") {
    $("#validateName").show();
    validation = false;
} else {
    $("#validateName").hide();
    values[field.name] = field.value;
}   
values['addmessage'] = '';
$.ajax({
    'url' : '',
    'type' : 'POST',
    'data' : values,
    success : function(data){

    }
});
```